# Show multiple columns in a DropDownDataWindow

Tags: drop-down-menu, powerbuilder

I have a legacy Powerbuilder application (now being updated to PB12.6 Classic) that fakes having multiple columns in its dropdowndatawindows by having a field called compute_1 which contains `dept_no + '    ' + dept_name`.

Unfortunately, this doesn't play nicely with the proportional font it uses. In VFP, I know I can get multiple columns in my comboboxes without having to worry about font widths. Is there any way to get the same effect in PB12.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to set multiple columns next to each other in the datawindow used in the dddw. Make sure you change the width to 100+ to ensure all columns are shown. The selected column result however should stay the compute_1 you already have if you want the selected showing when the dddw is closed.

Comment: *sigh* That was a little too obvious. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Actually, I made compute_1 invisible, so I don't have to worry about the various forms that already refer to it, and just dropped the two fields on top of it. Worked like a charm.